# Dynamic SQL Server Inner Join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am building a dynamic sql query which loops on the columns that are available and perform and innerjoin to return the duplicates values.

So far looping in the column is working as a charm. The only issue is when I am building the dynamic inner join  which is returning an error message. code is as below

```
DECLARE @Check VARCHAR(250) = 'Check_1'
DECLARE @SQLQUERY VARCHAR(MAX)


SET @SQLQUERY =  'SELECT  A.PostingDate,A.DocumentNumber,A.Account,A.Reference,A.'+@Check+'
FROM TblDataTemp A
INNER JOIN TblDataHistory B
ON A.'+@Check +' = B.'+@Check +';'

EXEC @SQLQUERY
```

> Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 12
>   The name 'SELECT A.PostingDate,A.DocumentNumber,A.Account,A.Reference,A.Check_1
>   FROM TblDataTemp A
>   INNER JOIN TblDataHistory B
>   ON A.Check_1 = B.Check_1;' is not a valid identifier.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just need to wrap the @sqlquery in parentheses. Currently it is reading the string text as an object-identifier, rather than a query.

Comment: it worked. thank you very much. i had put it in a previous query but omitted in that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using [`EXECUTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#c-using-execute-tsql_string-with-a-variable) with dynamic SQL, you must use parentheses. Otherwise, SQL Server thinks the variable contains a procedure name.

```
DECLARE @Check VARCHAR(250) = 'Check_1'
DECLARE @SQLQUERY VARCHAR(MAX)


SET @SQLQUERY =  'SELECT   A.PostingDate,A.DocumentNumber,A.Account,A.Reference,A.'+@Check+'
FROM TblDataTemp A
INNER JOIN TblDataHistory B
ON A.'+@Check +' = B.'+@Check +';'

EXEC (@SQLQUERY)
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest wrapping each of these variables with QUOTENAME to help reduce the risk of sql injection.